Function (magrittr pipe) can be used despite not exist()-ing or being on search path
Loading a package and then re-parenting .GlobalEnv yields unexpected behaviour: one specific function (the magrittr pipe) can still be called by name despite magrittr not being on the search path, and both exist() and getAnywhere() reporting that the function is not publicly accessible.
This popped up in the context of playing around to see if I could create a lightweight "isolated" evaluation environment a-la callr but without the overhead of spinning up a new R process.
To reproduce:
## Save the current "location" of .GlobalEnv, and shift it to a new location (i.e. set a new parent)
original_parent = parent.env(.GlobalEnv)
parent.env(.GlobalEnv) = new.env(parent=baseenv())

## Run some code including library() with .GlobalEnv in new location
library(magrittr)

exists("%>%") # TRUE
try("abc" %>% toupper) # ABC

## Reset location of .GlobalEnv to original position and unload the namespace
parent.env(.GlobalEnv) = original_parent

exists("%>%") # FALSE, as expected
try("abc" %>% toupper) # "ABC" <- ???

Running getAnywhere("%>%") shows that the function is still loaded in namespace:magrittr. However, my understanding is that since package:magrittr is not on the search path (due to the shenanigans with re-parenting .GlobalEnv), %>% should not be found by R and should instead give Error: object '%>%' not found. And in fact, if I unloadNamespace("magrittr") then getAnywhere() reports no hits but I still get the above behaviour.
I am (vaguely) aware from the docs that unloading a namespace may not unload DLLs and via getLoadedDLLs it seems plausible that the magrittr pipe is such an object (I don't understand this part of R well enough to be sure either way). However even if this is the reason for the pipe not being unloaded, I still don't understand why it is being picked up by the console when magrittr is not on the search path (and no other packages are re-exporting magrittr functions, as far as I'm aware) -- this seems totally counter to my understanding of how R evaluates code.
Could someone explain to me what is going on here? Thanks in advance!
[In case it is relevant, I'm running R 4.2.1 via Posit Workbench. My search path on a fresh session (i.e. just auto-loaded packages) is c(".GlobalEnv", "tools:rstudio", "package:stats", "package:graphics",  "package:grDevices", "package:utils", "package:datasets", "package:methods",  "Autoloads", "package:base"). As far as I can tell this is the only function from magrittr which has this unexpected behaviour (other functions seem not to be accessible once magrittr is taken off the search path). I haven't tested with any other packages.]

See "Details" in help("detach").  Also, "The replacement function parent.env<- is extremely dangerous as it can be used to destructively change environments in ways that violate assumptions made by the internal C code. It may be removed in the near future."

“Re-parenting” .GlobalEnv is not supported by R (though this limitation isn’t documented beyond the hand-wavy cop-out notice quoted by Roland). In fact, on older versions of R it straight-up caused a segfault. Use attach() and detach() instead, if you really need to. See the comment at https://github.com/klmr/box/blob/e0a64e3b5cab5ff5f3af21d34d373d2155390b4d/R/env.r#L208-L217

@Roland: I'm afraid I'm not getting any clarification from the "Details" of help("detach"): even if one of those caveats applies to magrittr::`%>%`  (and it's not at all clear to me that any of them do), then this still doesn't explain why %>% can be executed from console without magrittr being on the search path. Or is my understanding that execution within .GlobalEnv (specifically in code executed from the console) looks only at the search() environments (and attendant namespace and imports environments) completely mistaken?

@KonradRudolph When you say "not supported", should I take that to mean "you may encounter weird and counterintuitive outcomes, this is just one of those and there's no deeper logical explanation behind this"? If so fair enough -- that's a shame but oh well.
I'm still quite confused as to how R is locating the function if it's not in the search() path but maybe this is just something that breaks if you try to re-parent .GlobalEnv.

And for reference, I'm trying to do this in order to build an execution environment for "semi-trusted" scripts written by colleagues/others; as such I don't necessarily have the option to rewrite their code to use attach() in place of library() (I guess I could always just ask them nicely, but I'd prefer to just eat the cost of using callr if it meant I can support use of library()).

@byron It basically means that, yes. In C lingo it’s “undefined”: you are not allowed to do it, but there is no explicit check in place to prevent you. The resulting behaviour will just not be what you want/expect.

@byron "detaching will not in general unload any dynamically loaded compiled code (DLLs)". and "The most reliable way to completely detach a package is to restart R." unloadNamespace is a wrapper for detach.
